# how do I return anchors to their initial state after a visit

Tags: html, css

I have a chapter-navigation table, with about 50 entries, shown in blue per web custom. The text turns red on `a:hover`, because the active area is the text rather than the entire `<td>` area (despite efforts to make the whole area work), and green briefly on `a:active`. This much is intentional and working.

However, browsers remembers all visits and set a color which overrides my CSS until I clear its history. Is there a way to keep the browsers from messing with my links?

Comment: css `text-decoration: none` ?

Comment: an Anchor tag has 4 possible states 

a:link - a normal, unvisited link
a:visited - a link the user has visited
a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
a:active - a link the moment it is clicked

Use the "color" property on CSS to set the colors as per your preference.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: Looks like you accidentally created two accounts. You can [contact the team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have them merged, which will allow you to regain direct editing privileges on your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow this order.

1. `a:link`
2. `a:visited`
3. `a:hover`
4. `a:active`

If you write `a:hover` below `a:visited`, it will not work.

Comment: It's also worth styling the `:focus` state, not everyone uses a mouse to interact with a link.

Comment: @DavidThomas where does `:focus` come on this list? Last?

Comment: I tend to style it alongside the `:active` state.